# Is it possible to set a boolean option as 'true' by default in Rust's docopt?

Tags: rust, docopt

By default, a boolean field is set to `false`, but I want it set to `true` by default.

I tried to use `[default: true]` in the `docopt` description, but it seems `default` cannot be applied to a boolean option. I also tried to use Rust's `Default` trait - it doesn't work either.

The following is a minimal example:

```
extern crate rustc_serialize;
extern crate docopt;

use docopt::Docopt;

const USAGE: &'static str = "
Hello World. 

Usage:
  helloworld [options]

Options:
  --an-option-with-default-true   This option should by default be true
";

#[derive(Debug, RustcDecodable)]
struct Args {
    flag_an_option_with_default_true: bool,
}

impl Args {
    pub fn init(str: &str) -> Args {
        Docopt::new(USAGE)
            .and_then(|d| d.argv(str.split_whitespace().into_iter()).parse())
            .unwrap_or_else(|e| e.exit())
            .decode()
            .unwrap()
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain how you would set the value to false?

Comment: If there's no way to set it to `false`, then the problem is easily solved: `const FLAG_AN_OPTION_WITH_DEFAULT_TRUE: bool = true;`

Comment: @Shepmaster Errm, the issue is that if a flag defaults to true, then there is no way for an end user to set the flag to false. Because of that, it doesn't make sense to default a flag to true. A flag is either given (true) or not (false).

Comment: @BurntSushi5 I know, my comment was tongue-in-cheek ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The [author of the crate says it's not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42812626/155423), so that's as authoritative of an answer you can get.

---

As an *alternative*, you can take an argument that defaults to "true":

```
const USAGE: &'static str = "
Hello World. 

Usage:
  helloworld [options]

Options:
  --an-option=<arg>   This option should by default be true [default: true].
";

#[derive(Debug, RustcDecodable)]
struct Args {
    flag_an_option: String,
}

impl Args {
    // ...

    fn an_option(&self) -> bool {
        self.flag_an_option == "true"
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = Args::init("dummy");
    println!("{}", a.an_option()); // true

    let a = Args::init("dummy --an-option=false");
    println!("{}", a.an_option()); // false

    let a = Args::init("dummy --an-option=true");
    println!("{}", a.an_option()); // true
}
```

Or you could have a flag that has inverse logic:

```
const USAGE: &'static str = "
Hello World. 

Usage:
  helloworld [options]

Options:
  --disable-an-option
";

#[derive(Debug, RustcDecodable)]
struct Args {
    flag_disable_an_option: bool,
}

impl Args {
    // ... 

    fn an_option(&self) -> bool {
        !self.flag_disable_an_option
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = Args::init("dummy");
    println!("{}", a.an_option()); // true

    let a = Args::init("dummy --disable-an-option");
    println!("{}", a.an_option()); // false
}
```

Remember that you can implement methods on the parsed argument struct that make it easier to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Docopt itself does not provide a way to "disable" a flag, so if a flag defaulted to true---even when it's not given by an end user---then it would be impossible for that flag to ever be `false`.